# how can I print the last element of the array on the next line?

Tags: c

as the title says, how can I print the last element of the array on the next line?

note: this is in c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printArray();

int main()
{
    int arr[1000];
    int i, size;

    //Input array size
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter elements of the array:\n");

    //Input elements in array
    printf("");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    //Last element of the array
    printf("%d", size); //I feel like this is where my problem is, but I don't know what to change it with

    return 0;
}
```

---

expected output (example):

```
Enter array size: 5
Enter elements of the array:
12
34
56
78
90
90
```

what I get (example):

```
Enter array size: 5
Enter elements of the array:
12
34
56
78
90
5
```

any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Since you make no attempt to produce *any* output besides thee value of `size`, I can't fathom how you expect `90` to be printed rather than `5`. Unrelated `printf("");` is *completely* worthless.

Answer (score 3):

You need to index the array itself, rather than just printing the size. Note that you need to subtract one from the index since C arrays are 0-indexed, i.e., the first element is at index 0 and the last is at index `size-1`. Add `\n` to print on a new line.

```
printf("%d\n", arr[size-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you do not get the expected output is you pass the `size` to `printf` instead of the last array element `arr[size - 1]`.

Note also these remarks:

- you should always check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input as well as the value entered to avoid undefined behavior is `size <= 0` or `size > 1000`.
- `printf("")` has no effect.
- it is recommended to always end the output with a newline. Printing the element value with just `%d` and exiting the program will cause the shell prompt to appear just after the number's digits, causing some confusion if for example the shell prompt is `%` .

C is a sharp tool that is easily mishandled.  There are no runtime checks and compilers are very lax by default.  I strongly recommend to use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to get extra compile time error checking, or `/W4` with Microsoft compilers.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[1000];
    int size;

    // Input and validate array size
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (size <= 0 || size > 1000) {
        printf("invalid size: %d, must be in the range 1 to 1000\n", size);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter elements of the array:\n");

    // Input elements in array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid or missing input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Output the last element of the array
    printf("%d\n", arr[size - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do with `printf("%d",arr[i-1]);`

- As `i` recently incremented after exiting the loop